# Flex database - HTTP call collision?

Tags: web-services, sqlite, apache-flex

I have a Flex application for AIR. I fetch some data from a JSON-RPC web service through the `mx.rpc.http.HTTPService` class. I make all the calls asynchronously. When the results return I process them and put the data into an SQLite database through the `flash.data.SQLConnection`. This means quite some updates per web service calls so every callback starts a transaction, does the updates and then commits.

According to my debug console tracing I see two kinds of behaviour: either a callback successfully begins a transaction, calls the transaction event handler function, does all the updates, commits and then the next web service call returns. Or a callback successfully begins a transaction and as the next web service call returns (without trying to start a new transaction yet) the previous callback just... ceases to exist even before the callback of the beginning of the transaction.

Is that a bug in Flex? Or in AIR? Or in ActionScript? Or in the specific components? Do I do something wrong? Is this just my misunderstanding? (I'm just trying my wings in Flex, I don't really know what to expect from the system or how to handle this situation.)

Some code from my database manager class

```
public function beginTransaction(handler:Function):void {
    // The calls are all fine up to this point
    conn.begin(SQLTransactionLockType.DEFERRED, new Responder(handler, OnError));
    // Begin is always called first. If another web service call doesn't come
    // back up to this point then it won't until I call commit in an other
    // function.
    trace("this always runs yet");
    // But if another call comes back just after begin is called then handler
    // won't get called. Even though the previous trace still will.
}
```

My web service call

```
public function getWSCall(url:String, method:String, param:Object,
                          handler:Function):void
{
    var http:HTTPService = new HTTPService();

    http.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, JsonError);
    http.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, handler);
    http.url = url;
    http.method = "POST";
    http.contentType = "application/json";

    var params:Object = {};
    params.jsonrpc = "2.0";
    params.method = method;
    if (param !== null)
        params.params = param;
    params.id = method;
    var json:String = JSON.stringify(params);
    trace (url + " " + json);

    http.send(json);
}
```

And an example of how I call it

```
JsonConnector.instance.getWSCall(WSConstants.GET_DATA_URL,
    WSConstants.GET_DATA_METHOD, param, getDataCompleted);
```

And in the `getDataCompleted` after some rearrangement I call my database manager class where I finally begin the transaction:

```
dbConnector.Open(key, opened);

function opened(event:SQLEvent):void
{
    if(event.type == SQLEvent.OPEN) {
        dbConnector.beginTransaction(onBegin);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you're trying to do; and I don't understand the functionality you are asking about. Is the problem with fetching the JSON-RPC data?  Or with saving data to the local database?

Comment: I can fetch the data fine. I can save the data fine. But seemingly if some other data arrives in the exact moment when a transaction has been initiated but the callback for that (`handler` in my case) has not been called yet then it just won't get called. Or at least this is what I see from it.

Comment: How does the "some other data arrive?  Show us the code behind how that data is retrieved and processed.  If I had to guess; it sounds like the second call is overwriting the first call.

Comment: Yes, what Reboog said... Show the code you use to deal with the HTTPService, in particular how you wire up the response/fault handlers for your HTTP requests. Since HTTP requests are asynchronous, it's possible for responses to be recieved out of order. We usually use an AsyncToken to keep track of requests. You'll likely want to add that to your mix so your database manager can manage the process.

Comment: I added a little more code